# How to store data (real time) get from the energy meter to SQL Server database (to get data I use modscan software)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, data-acquisition, database-connectivity

I want to get the power values of energy meter to PC and store it in a SQL Server database as shiftwise (like 8am to 5pm) and display the organized values through Windows Forms interface. I have used modscan software to get data to computer and I want to store that data to data base.

The way I got the data is (Energy Meter (RS485) ---> RS485 to RS232 converter ---> RS232 to USB converter ---> Windows PC) now I want to store that data to data base I made in Microsoft SQL Server,as shiftwise data.

After that I will get the data from server and display it in Visual Studio interface. I want to know is this a easy way or are their any other ways and how to add data to the database.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the whole project at a high level.  We don't need that much detail.  What is the specific part of your question that you need help with?  After you do all of that with the USB converter and what not, what is the format of the data?  After you narrow down the question, please provide more information about what you have tried to specifically answer that narrow question.

Comment: I want to Display the power that used the the whole Day in shifts(eg. 8 am - 5pm ___KWH). I want to make the user friendly interface and display the values in that interface (shift wise values ), because it is easy to understand the power consumption. I want it every day shiftwise values to store and display when day enter and press the button.